Building in eclipse gives an Tycho Packaging Plugin Error
Eclipse version 2024-06 is using the tycho plugin, but the build with maven generates following error.
Invalid plugin execution mapping (plugin execution "org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-packaging-plugin:4.0.7:build-qualifier
(execution: default-build-qualifier, phase: validate)").
To enable full functionality, correct the invalid mapping and run Maven->Update Project Configuration.
pom.xml Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem


See https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/discussions/1290

I don't use any plugin for Tycho in Eclipse. I just followed https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html You generally don't need any pom.xml with eclipse-plugin packaging, tycho works everything out itself for plugins.
